# Deserialize XML with array in custom namespace

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I'm trying to deserialize such an XML

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://schemas.ipcommerce.com/CWS/v2.0/Rest" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorId>7002</ErrorId>
    <HelpUrl>http://docs.nabvelocity.com/hc/en-us/articles/203497757-REST-Information</HelpUrl>
    <Messages xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:string>An invalid security token was provided.</a:string>
    </Messages>
    <Operation>SignOn</Operation>
    <Reason i:nil="true"/>
    <ValidationErrors/>
</ErrorResponse>
```

into such an object with its static method

```
  [XmlRoot("ErrorResponse", Namespace = "http://schemas.ipcommerce.com/CWS/v2.0/Rest")]
  public class VelocityException
  {
    public int ErrorId { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Messages", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
    public string[] Messages { get; set; }

    public static VelocityException FromXmlString(string xml)
    {
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VelocityException), );
      return (VelocityException)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
    }
  }
```

however, after deserialization, the array Messages are always null. How do I set up the custom namespace prefix for deserialization of that strings array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of XmlArray, use XmlArrayItem. Also, remove the "Messages" and use "string" instead since your Messages is a list of "string" (a:string)

This works,

```
[XmlRoot("ErrorResponse", Namespace = "http://schemas.ipcommerce.com/CWS/v2.0/Rest")]
public class VelocityException
{
    public int ErrorId { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("string", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] Messages { get; set; }

    public static VelocityException FromXmlString(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VelocityException));
        return (VelocityException)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
    }
}
```